# I need to set my app content offline

Tags: android

I am getting my content from json through server.I have two TextView and one ImageView in my layout.i have written the content from json to a file. but i not able to set my data while offline
I am  getting the data from a file also.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    private Context context;

    private NavigationView mNavigationView;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    NewsAdapter  adapter;
    ArrayList<News> Newslist;

    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static String url = "https://www.amrita.edu/amrita_api/v1/news_android.jsonp";

    String image;
    String imageurl;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
   // ArrayList<String> newsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    WebView descWView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_json);
        Newslist = new ArrayList<News>();
        context=getApplicationContext();
        //initViews();
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

         getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.app_icon);

        initViews();
        initContentWebView();
        setUpNavDrawer();
        new GetContacts().execute();

    }

    private void initViews(){

        mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    }


    void initContentWebView(){

        String htmlText = " %s ";
       // ArrayList<String> myData = newsList;
      //  descWView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.content_wview);

       // String htmlData= "<html><body style='text-align:justify;font-size:"+getResources().getInteger(R.integer.main_text)+"px'><p>'sajhdsakjc;osalcjklsx'</p>"+myData.toString()+"</body></Html >";


        //descWView.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
        // descWView.loadData(htmlData, "text/html", "utf-8");


        // descWView.loadDataWithBaseURL(String.format(htmlText, htmlData), String.valueOf(myData), "text/html", "UTF-8", String.format(htmlText, htmlData));
        // descWView.s(myData);
    }


    private void setUpNavDrawer() {

        mDrawerToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout,mToolbar,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        String item=menuItem.getTitle().toString();
        String dPath=menuItem.getTitleCondensed().toString();
        if(item.equals("News")){
            //this.finish();
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            this.finish();
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "god", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        else if(item.equals("Events")){
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, EventActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            this.finish();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "god1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(item.equals("Latest Publications")){
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "god2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if(item.equals("Students Achivements")){
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "god3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(item.equals("Important Announcements")){
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "god4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(item.equals("Research")){
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ResearchActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            this.finish();
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "god5", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(item.equals("Ranking")){
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "god6", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, RankingActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            this.finish();
        }
        else if(item.equals("International")){
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "god7", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, InternationalActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            this.finish();

        }
        else if(item.equals("About")){
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AboutActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            this.finish();
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "god8", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(item.equals("Contact Us")) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "god9", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ContactUs.class);
            intent.putExtra("keyId", item);
            intent.putExtra("descPath",dPath);

            startActivity(intent);
            // this.finish();
        }
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_share) {
            /*Intent intent=new Intent(context,AboutActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;*/ Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "msg msg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();


        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
           // arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {

                JSONArray jsonarray = null;

                try {
                    jsonarray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                    for (int i = 0; i <jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        News news = new News();
                        JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject jsonimage=jsonobject.getJSONObject("image");
                        //Log.d(String.valueOf(jsonimage), String.valueOf(jsonimage.length()));
                        String imageurl=jsonimage.getString("filename");


                        // System.out.println(imageurl);
                        // Retrive JSON Objects

                        news.setTitle(jsonobject.getString("title"));
                        news.setBody(jsonobject.getString("body"));
                       // news.setImage(jsonobject.getString("image"));
                        news.setImage(jsonimage.getString("filename"));



                        // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                        Newslist.add(news);
                        /*image = jsonobject.getString("image");
                        String title = jsonobject.getString("title");
                        String content = jsonobject.getString("content");
                        newsList.add(image);
                        newsList.add(title);
                        newsList.add(content);*/
                        // Log.d(newsList.get(i),"image");
                        // Log.d(title,"title");

                        // System.out.println("All MinQuantitiy"+newsList);

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

               /* try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    Log.d(jsonStr,"json");
                    // Getting JSON Array node
                   JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("news");

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    *//*for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString("id");
                        String name = c.getString("name");
                        String email = c.getString("email");
                        String address = c.getString("address");
                        String gender = c.getString("gender");

                        // Phone node is JSON Object
                        JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject("phone");
                        String mobile = phone.getString("mobile");
                        String home = phone.getString("home");
                        String office = phone.getString("office");

                        // tmp hash map for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put("id", id);
                        contact.put("name", name);
                        contact.put("email", email);
                        contact.put("mobile", mobile);

                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);
                    }*//*
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }*/

            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }

            return null;

        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            int sizeofarray= Newslist.size();
            ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
            viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomPagerAdapter(context,sizeofarray ));


            viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                TextView tvtitle=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvtitle);
                TextView tvbody=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvbody);
                ImageView im=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.NewsImage);
                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                    for(position=0;position<20;position++) {
                        tvtitle.setText(Newslist.get(position).getTitle());
                        tvbody.setText(Newslist.get(position).getBody());

                       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),position//, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                }
            });


           // im.setImageResource(String.format("https://www.amrita.edu/sites/default/files/%s", Newslist.get().getImage()));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"sizeNewslist"+sizeofarray, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
            /*for(int i=1;i<3;i++){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                       "aaa"+newsLists,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }*/

          /* ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, newsList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"name", "email",
                    "content"}, new int[]{R.id.image,
                    R.id.title, R.id.co});

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);*/
        }



    }
}



   /* public interface ClickListener {
        void onClick(View view, int position);

        void onLongClick(View view, int position);
    }*/
```

adapter class

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    String image_url;
    private Context mContext;
    int size;
    ArrayList<News> Newslist;
    File file,file1;
    StringBuffer buffer,buffer1;
    DataHandler handler;
    public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context, int arraysize, ArrayList<News> newslist) {
        mContext = context;
        size=arraysize;
        Newslist=newslist;

    }



    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {

        ModelObject modelObject = ModelObject.values()[position];
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, collection, false);

        collection.addView(layout);
        TextView tvtitle=(TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.tvtitle);
        TextView tvbody=(TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.tvbody);
        ImageView im=(ImageView)layout.findViewById(R.id.NewsImage);
        im.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

        SugarContext.init(mContext);

      ConnectivityManager ConnectionManager=(ConnectivityManager)mContext.getSystemService(mContext.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo=ConnectionManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()==true )
        {



            tvtitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(Newslist.get(position).getTitle()));
            tvbody.setText(Html.fromHtml(Newslist.get(position).getBody()));

            image_url = "https://www.amrita.edu/sites/default/files/" + Newslist.get(position).getImage();
            Picasso.with(mContext).load(image_url).into(im);

/*****************88*/
            ArrayList<News> content = Newslist;
            // String content="hello";
            File file,file1;
            FileOutputStream outputStream,outputStream1;
            try {
                //file = File.createTempFile("MyCache", null,getCacheDir());
                file = new File(mContext.getCacheDir(), "newstitle");
                file1 = new File(mContext.getCacheDir(), "newsbody");

                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                outputStream1 = new FileOutputStream(file1);
                outputStream.write(content.get(position).getTitle().getBytes());
                outputStream1.write(content.get(position).getBody().getBytes());
                //outputStream.write(Integer.parseInt(content.get(position).getImage()));
                // outputStream.write(Integer.parseInt(content.get(position).getTitle()));
                // outputStream.write(Integer.parseInt(content.get(position).getBody()));
                outputStream.close();
                Log.d("filecreated", String.valueOf(file));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            BufferedReader input = null;
            BufferedReader input1=null;
            file = null;
            file1=null;
            try {
                file = new File(mContext.getCacheDir(), "newstitle");
                file1 = new File(mContext.getCacheDir(), "newsbody");// Pass getFilesDir() and "MyFile" to read file

                input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
                input1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file1)));
                String line,line1;

                buffer = new StringBuffer();
                buffer1 = new StringBuffer();
                while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }
                while ((line1 = input1.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer1.append(line1);
                }
                String s=buffer.toString();
                String t=buffer1.toString();
                //Log.d("bufferdsample", buffer.toString());
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "asas"+s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "body"+t, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
/*****************************88*/


          /* try {
        handler = new DataHandler(mContext);
                handler.open();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "exc " + e,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            handler.insertData(Newslist.get(position).getImage(),Newslist.get(position).getTitle(),Newslist.get(position).getBody());
*/
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Network Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        else
        {



            BufferedReader input = null;
            BufferedReader input1=null;
            file = null;
            file1=null;
            try {
                file = new File(mContext.getCacheDir(), "newstitle");
                file1 = new File(mContext.getCacheDir(), "newsbody");// Pass getFilesDir() and "MyFile" to read file

                input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
                input1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file1)));
                String line,line1;

                buffer = new StringBuffer();
                buffer1 = new StringBuffer();
                while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }
                while ((line1 = input1.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer1.append(line1);
                }
                String s=buffer.toString();
                String t=buffer1.toString();
                //Log.d("bufferdsample", buffer.toString());
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "asas"+s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "body"+t, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Network Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

           /* image_url = "https://www.amrita.edu/sites/default/files/" + Newslist.get(position).getImage();
            Picasso.with(mContext).load(image_url).into(im);*/
        }

        /* String fileName="cachefile";

       try {
            cacheThis.writeObject(mContext, fileName, Newslist);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            Newslist.addAll((List<News>) cacheThis.readObject(mContext, fileName));
            Log.d("aaasasa", String.valueOf(Newslist));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
        // ImageLoader class instance


        // whenever you want to load an image from url
        // call DisplayImage function
        // url - image url to load
        // loader - loader image, will be displayed before getting image
        // image - ImageView


        //im.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL("https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-yEE6FqiglKw/VeBH_MmGGzI/AAAAAAAAbHE/HUYcYvkIwl0/s1600/AndroidImageViewSetImageFromURL2.png"));
      // im.setImageResource(Uri.parse("https://www.amrita.edu/sites/default/files/%s", Newslist.get(position).getImage()));
     // new DownloadImageTask(im).execute("https://www.amrita.edu/sites/default/files/" + Newslist.get(position).getImage());


        return layout;
    }




/*public void ofline(View view){
    String filr_name="newfile";
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = mContext.OpenfileOutput(filr_name,MODE_PRIVATE)

}

    public void readmessage(View view){

    }*/


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
        collection.removeView((View) view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        ModelObject customPagerEnum = ModelObject.values()[position];

        return mContext.getString(customPagerEnum.getTitleResId());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When device  is offline you can import /read  from a File or database which contains this json value . After getting internet update the database or file .

For file you must make or move the file in

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

And for writing in a file follow the code

```
private void writeToFile(String data,Context context) {
try {
    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput("test.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
    outputStreamWriter.write(data);
    outputStreamWriter.close();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
} 
}
```

And reading from external storage follow the following code

```
private String readFromFile(Context context) {

String ret = "";

try {
    InputStream inputStream = context.openFileInput("test.txt");

    if ( inputStream != null ) {
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        String receiveString = "";
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
            stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
        }

        inputStream.close();
        ret = stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
}

return ret;
}
```

Comment: Sir thanks for the rply..but in my code i am able to write and read from file .. but mu problem is that i am not able to set my written data to textview. plz can u suggest me option .

Comment: textview.setText(var) isn't working after calling the readFromFile()  method ??

Comment: no. i tried that method..(tvtitle.setText(buffer.toString());)  but this nt wrking. i giv this code under connectivitymanager check... i network i there then i vill read the data dirctly from json and same time i write the data to a file  after that if nonetwrk then i read from the file .. and give the code"tvtitle.setText(buffer.toString());" to set to my textview bit it not settting the data

Comment: Android may auto-delete the files in CacheDir once the system gets low on memory. Third party can also delete it .avoid using this .

Comment: Anyway your code is too dirty .read this http://ricardogeek.com/docs/clean_code.pdf book

Comment: Its totally up to you . You can't push large value in a single row . So you have to parse the data and insert it properly .Use file or shared Preference to avoid database related coding ..
Thanks